# Multiple Widgets in Form Field - Django Forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm working on a form in Django and it has a select element with a unique ID. This is what I'm currently doing:

```
instance_type = forms.CharField(label='Instance Type', widget=forms.Select(choices=INSTANCE_TYPES),
                                    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'id':'instance_type'}))
```

The problem is that Django is giving me a syntax error that says:

```
 SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated: widget
```

I need to combine these two widgets into one, but haven't found a solution to it.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you all!

Comment: In which way do you want to combine a `Select` with `TextInput`? Maybe, you are looking for something like [this](https://select2.org/dropdown)?

Comment: Just remove the second widget and define your CHOICES tuple like this `CHOICES = [('1', 'First'), ('2', 'Second')]`